# In Solr how to convert scientific notation values into normal values?

Tags: solr

As part of Solr query response I am getting double type field values in scientific notation (exponential format).

How to get values in normal number format as part of Solr respons. What should be my solr query?

Sample response

{
        "field_1":1,
        "field_2":abc,
        **"field_3":1.266534506E7,**
   },

In above example "field_3" values contains scientific notation format 1.266534506E7. Expecting value in normal number format 12665345.06.

Comment: Are you sure that's actually on Solr? My guess is that JSON serializes as a float, and a float is represented like that as its standard tostring. Either format it client side, or if it's actual currency, use the `currency` type if you need to do math on it, otherwise a plain string might be enough if all numbers are formatted the same way.

Comment: Yes, you are corrrect !!!, JSON is serializing as float, I have no option to handle at client side.